# Why the expected probing times between the successful search and insertion of the element in the Open addressing hashing is different?

Tags: algorithm

In third edititon of the Introduction to Algorithms,about the open addressing hashing,It analyzes the expected probing times of the unsuccessful search and insertion of elements,as well as the unsuccessful search.

There are detailed computations about these,but I am thinking about that if we suppose it is a uniform hashing,then we can consider the insertion is just the unsuccessful search because they are doing the same thing--to find a null slot,and the expected probing times are 1/(1-a)(a is the load factor).

Meanwhile the probing sequence of successful search and  insertion of the element is the same,to insert the element,we need to prob about 1/(1-a) slots to find the right position,then when we serch the element,in principle we need to traverse the same sequence,so it should be 1/(1-a) too.but the real sitution is the expected times of successful search is (1/a)ln(1/(1-a)).

I can understand the process of the computation of these conclusions.But I can not find the essential reason for the difference between the successful search and insertion/unsuccessful search,is there any help?

Comment: Could you take 5mins to properly format your question? It is really hard to read such a huge block of text that has no visible paragraphs or anything. Just familirize with the editor.

Comment: For unsuccessful search you always have to go to the end of the collision chain. For successful search most of the records will be found earlier in the chain.

Comment: @Zabuza,Thank you for this suggestion,and I am sorry for the bad edition.

Comment: @Henry,but in the open addressing hashing,the unsuccessful search happens when the empty slot is found or the all slots are traversed.I think you are saying about the chaining hashing.Or maybe I do not understand you very well.

Comment: There is still the case that two different records hash to the same index. In this case, one needs to look for another index (how this is done depends on the probing strategy). Several repetitions may be necessary if the table is rather full. The indexes probed in this way form the collision chain.

Comment: @Henry,oh,I got it.maybe I can solve it now.Thank you very much.